# Code generation with php-class-html-generator

Tags: php, html

I am trying to reproduce the following markup with [php-class-html-generator](https://code.google.com/p/php-class-html-generator/), but I am stuck with inserting `<i>` and setting text at the end, just before `</h4>`

Original HTML

```
<h4 class="formTitle lead">
    <span class="widget-number"><i class="icon-comments"></i></span>Random
</h4>
```

My Code:

```
$h4 = HTMLTag::createElement('h4')->setText("Random")
    ->addClass('formTitle')
    ->addClass('lead');
$h4->addElement('span')
    ->addClass('widget-number');
return($h4);
```

My output at the moment:

```
<h4 class="formTitle lead">
     <span class="widget-number">Random</span>
</h4>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You question is not clear. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want to reproduce original html with php-class-html-generator :)

Comment: I'd like to help, if I knew how to use it. Looks like a good script.

Comment: Getting the hang of it. Cool script, `upvoting all` for this great find, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

```
$h4 = HTMLTag::createElement('h4')->setText("Random")->addClass('formTitle')->addClass('lead');

$span = $h4->addElement('span')->addClass('widget-number');

$i = $span->addElement('i')->setText(' ')->addClass('icon-comments');
```

**Result** -

```
    <h4 class="formTitle lead">
<span class="widget-number">
<i class="icon-comments"></i></span>Random</h4>
```